# How to cancel validation in onValueChanged function in angular?

Tags: angular, validation, onchange

How to cancel validation in onValueChanged function in angular?

[Here is demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uehmh2?file=src/app/app.component.html)

When I finish the form, I change the device value. You can see that a validation will be trigger in the apple phone. However, I set the validation in the field touched. I don't want to show this message while I click the device (onValueChanged function). It trigger the "touched" validation. Any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change the form control to `pristine` and `untouched`. Then form validations will not show.

```
  deviceListOnChange(e) {
    this.updateForm.controls.apple.setValue(null);
    this.updateForm.controls.apple.markAsPristine();
    this.updateForm.controls.apple.markAsUntouched();
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guqanr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)